# How can I retrieve item values as an array with a Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.List in C#?

Tags: c#, sql-server, sharepoint

I'm using a C# script task in SSIS and I'd like to be able to feed SharePoint data to SQL Server. The only way I can think of is to get the data into an array of some sort and build a query using that array. I've build a ListItemCollection, but I'm not sure how to actually pull strings from it to put it into an array.

```
List list = web.Lists.GetByTitle("ListTitle");
ListItemCollection listItemCollection = list.GetItems(CamlQuery.CreateAllItemsQuery());
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

Can this be done, or is there an easier way to get it to SQL Server?

Comment: A script task uses same options as the SQLCMD.EXE (command line executable that comes with SQL Server).  SQLCMD.EXE has an option to write data to CSV.  ExecuteQuery writes one row at a time which is slow.  It is much fast to bulk import into database.  You may want to try one of the command line executable for SQL : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/command-prompt-utility-reference-database-engine?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: So my best option is to write to a CSV and then import that CSV into SQL Server? Can this be automated without needing an actual CSV file? Hoping to run this on a server.

Comment: I don't like adding large amount of data at the end of a command line especially if there are returns in the line.  I use the Process class to execute these commands from c#.  Sometimes a save a bat file and run the bat file, other times I just use the Process class along with Process Parameters.  The parameters will indicate if the import file is csv, or tab delimited.  For huge files I always recommend using SQLCMD.EXE  because it is much faster then straight c#.  SQLCMD.EXE is written to archive huge database and is written very efficiently.

Comment: I see. I'm pretty new to C#, do you have any reference material on how to get a Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.List into a CSV format with C#?

Comment: Do a web search for following.  Lots of examples : microsoft sharepoint client list csv